# How do you match up your webdesign to make it pixel perfect?

Tags: css

I often find myself in the need for matching up my webdesign to some reference-image. I used to use the PixelPerfect plugin for FireBug, to overlay an image on top of my design - however these days I mostly develop in Chrome, and there isn't a comparable tool to PixelPerfect.

My perfect tool would be some kind of HUD display that would overlay the entire screen, so I could use it disregarding whatever browser I'm currently working in.

How do you match up your webdesign to make it pixel perfect? Any tools and tips is highly appreciated.

Comment: with Photoshop, using layer opacity.  Otherwise, not sure what you really mean.

Comment: Sorry, that downvote came in a moment of internet weakness. Pixel perfection really is overrated, but I'll add a real answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try online service like [makiapp.com](http://makiapp.com) it just like pixelperfect for firebug.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 13):

> How do you match up your webdesign to make it pixel perfect?

Don't, seriously.

There are so many devices and browsers and other factors that mean that, today more than ever, designs cannot be pixel perfect. To even try and make them so is going to cost a lot of time.

People don't compare websites between browsers so save yourself some valuable time and sanity!

Answer (score 2):

A great way that I've seen done involves work on both ends, but it works nicely.

First, make sure that your designs fit a grid: repeating, same-sized columns with fixed width gutters. You can take that grid layer and turn it into a background image that you apply to your containers during development. That way, if anything doesn't line up with the grid, you'll see it immediately.

Comment: Yep, I'm doing that on another project. I'm a big fan of Blueprint CSS :)